# Xcode project failing on build - main.storyboard

Tags: ios, xcode, swift, build, crash-reports

I have no idea why my Xcode project is failing when I try to build it. I built it about five minutes before but now I'm getting critical error from main.storyboard. There are two different folders, I have no idea what may be going wrong. The only thing I did was install a pod but even after uninstalling it I'm still getting the error.

Folders (Google Drive): https://drive.google.com/folderview?id=0B5eEmV9swrdaSy1xVGFETXoyd1E&usp=sharing

Comment: Gabe, short of posting your complete project to github so that others can look at the complete picture, this question is very difficult to answer. You didn't back it up before you installed the pod I guess?

Comment: @user3069232 This is my first project with Xcode, I wish I would have. I tried moving all the files to a new project but that didn't work either. As you said, I added my project to GitHub: https://github.com/TheLamp/WSDAPP  If anyone could help me out, please do.